# Redirect to URL based on Query Parameter after 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, redirect

I'll keep it short.

I have a WordPress page and need to redirect users to another URL after 4 seconds. This URL is a query parameter.

Here is an example.

They land on my page with this URL:

https://koniecstresu.sk/dakujem5/?wj_lead_unique_link_live_room=https%3A%2F%2Fevent.webinarjam.com%2Fgo%2Flive%2F15%2Fmqx6vt5coriq3rforg

The wj_lead_unique_link_live_room is the parameter.

And in this instance, they need to be redirected to this URL after 4 seconds: https://event.webinarjam.com/go/live/15/mqx6vt5coriq3rforg

I need to do this in HTML and JavaScript, which I can embed to the WordPress page in Elementor... tried to do it many different ways, but I could not figure out how to first get the URL parameter.

Thank y'all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the parameter is set using [URLSearchParams](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/), and if the parameter exists, then add a timeout that redirects after 4 seconds to the given target.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href)

if( params.has('wj_lead_unique_link_live_room') ) {
    const redirectUrl = decodeURIComponent(params.get('wj_lead_unique_link_live_room'))
    setTimeout(() => window.location.href = redirectUrl, 4000)
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this and I put it inside <script>, but for some reason, it's not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSearchParams for search params in the URL. check the code below. code will go to the active theme functions.php file.

```
function redirect_to_given_url_based_on_params(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var params = new URLSearchParams( window.location.href );
            if( params.has( 'wj_lead_unique_link_live_room' ) ) {
                var redirect_url = decodeURIComponent( params.get( 'wj_lead_unique_link_live_room' ) );
                setTimeout( function() {
                    window.location.href = redirec_url;
                }, 4000 );
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_to_given_url_based_on_params', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hey there, the redirect URL is supposed to be changed based on what follows after wj_lead_unique_link_live_room=

Comment: I put that code into Codesnippets, but for some reason, it doesn't do anything when I go to https://koniecstresu.sk/dakujem5/?wj_lead_unique_link_live_room=https%3A%2F%2Fevent.webinarjam.com%2Fgo%2Flive%2F15%2Fmqx6vt5coriq3rforg